# pivot_longer for large time series dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyverse, gis

I have a DF that contains a location identifier (county) and then multiple variables for multiple  years. I am trying to `pivot_longer` the data so there are entries for each county/year with the associated variables for each specific year.

I have two questions. First, is it necessary to covert this to long? It is associated with a shapefile and I plan to use the `sf` package for mapping, and then run several spatial regressions. Secondly, if I do need to convert to long, how do transform the wide DF to a long DF with so many variables to pivot?

Below is a small sample dataset that illustrates the issue: I have the following data:

```
wide_DF <- tibble::tribble(
  ~county,    ~geog,    ~var1_1990,   ~var1_2000,   ~var1_2010,    ~var2_1990,   ~var2_2000,   ~var2_2010,
  "Adams",     90.2,     2286,         2276,         2539,          2687,         1441,         2464,
  "Clark",     88.5,     2148,         2211,         2153,          2465,         1725,         2457,
  "Boulder",   -25.2,    2583,         1500,         2595,          2626,         1870,         2796,
)
```

And I would like to convert to the following:

```
long_DF <- tibble::tribble(
  ~county,     ~geog,  ~year,    ~var1,    ~var2,
  "Adams",      90.2,   1990,     2286,     2687,
  "Adams",      90.2,   2000,     2276,     1441,
  "Adams",      90.2,   2010,     2539,     2464,
  "Clark",      88.5,   1990,     2148,     2465,
  "Clark",      88.5,   2000,     2211,     1725,
  "Clark",      88.5,   2010,     2153,     2457,
  "Boulder",    -25.2,  1990,     2583,     2626,
  "Boulder",    -25.2,  2000,     1500,     1870,
  "Boulder",    -25.2,  2010,     2595,     2796,
)
```

My actual data has about 30,000 "county" equivalents over five years, with about 60 var1, var2 equivalents. Additionally, these files are associated with several columns of GIS information that will need to carry over with the pivot.

I have tried most iterations of the `pivot_longer` function in the `tidyverse` but am flummoxed with the amount of variables I need to pivot and that they are suffixed rather than prefixed, which pivot_long/wide does not seem to support.

Comment: Technical question answered below by @AndrewGB. What about best practices for spatio-temporal data and the Tidyverse? Is it best for shapefile data with attributes to be in tidy format or wide format?

Comment: Usually, having data in a long or wide format depends entirely on what you need to do with it. But for spatial data, it is much easier to summarize and do spatial analysis with only having one geometry per observation. But that really goes for most of `tidyverse`. It does have function to work across rows, but your code can end up being more verbose depending on what you are doing. So, a lot of people will pivot data long, then summarise, then pivot back to wide if they need it in that format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `names_sep` to split the column names into multiple columns. For `names_to`, we use `.value` so that any of the variables (prior to the separator, `_`) will be returned in their own column. Then, the value after the `_` will be returned to `year`.

```
library(tidyverse)

wide_DF %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(county, geog),
    names_sep = "_",
    names_to = c(".value", "year")
  )
```

**Output**

```
  county   geog year   var1  var2
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Adams    90.2 1990   2286  2687
2 Adams    90.2 2000   2276  1441
3 Adams    90.2 2010   2539  2464
4 Clark    88.5 1990   2148  2465
5 Clark    88.5 2000   2211  1725
6 Clark    88.5 2010   2153  2457
7 Boulder -25.2 1990   2583  2626
8 Boulder -25.2 2000   1500  1870
9 Boulder -25.2 2010   2595  2796
```

Comment: This is the solution for pivoting to long data. Thanks! I knew it was simple but I was getting lost in the amount of variables and observations I am using.

Comment: Luckily, the `pivot_...` functions have a lot of additional arguments that make this much simpler.